# Php no attributes needed?

Tags: php, arrays, attributes

normally using java. I ve seen a snippet like this today

```
$oStrategie = new Strategie();

foreach($aData as $key=>$value) {
        $oStrategie[$key] = $value;
}

$oStrategie->doSomething()
```

Strategie is a selfmade php class with nothing special. simple constructor doing nothing important and so on.

in the class Strategie the method doSomething() accesses the ArrayValues of $aData

```
$this['array_index_1']
```

Why can i access the array there even if the Strategie class doesent have any attributes defined and no setter overwritten or something like that? Can anybody explain me whats happening there? Is there no need to have attributes in the class in php???

Comment: 5.3 i think does that matter?

Comment: I ve just seen that Strategie extends another class that implements the interface ArrayAccess..  is this perhaps the reason? if yes what does this mean and how does it work?

Comment: @JannisHanke RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/arrayaccess) interface. This means it implements the following methods:

```
ArrayAccess {
    abstract public boolean offsetExists ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public mixed offsetGet ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public void offsetSet ( mixed $offset , mixed $value )
    abstract public void offsetUnset ( mixed $offset )
}
```

This allows you to use array access `$var[$offset]` on instances of this class. Here's a standard implement of a class like this, using a `$container` array to hold properties:

```
class Strategie implements ArrayAccess {

    private $container = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = array(
            "something"   => 1,
        );
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

Without looking at the actual implementation of `Strategie` or the class it's derived from, it's hard to tell what it's actually doing.

But using this, you can control the behavior of the class, for example, when accessing an offset that doesn't exist. Suppose we replace `offsetGet($offset)` with:

```
public function offsetGet($offset) {
    if (isset($this->container[$offset])) {
        return $this->container[$offset];
    } else {
        Logger.log('Tried to access: ' + $offset);
        return $this->default;
    }
}
```

Now whenever we try to access an offset that doesn't exist, it will return a default (eg: `$this->default`) and log an error, for example.

Note that you can accomplish similar behavior using the magic methods [`__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set), [`__get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get), [`__isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) and [`__unset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.unset). The difference between the magic methods I just listed and `ArrayAccess` is that you'd access a property via `$obj->property` rather than `$obj[offset]`

Comment: Ah ok i found some information about this interface..  this was the hint i needed.. thank u very much

Comment: Since the question was about adding attributes dynamically, it will be useful to inform the OP that you can always add new attributes that weren't defined on the object `$oStrategie->newAttr = 6`

Comment: @JuanMendes That would require you to use `__set()` rather than `ArrayAccess` though.

Comment: I'm not talking about `ArrayAccess` or `__set()`, which allows you to hook into what I'm talking about (setting undeclared attributes). I'm just saying that PHP allows you to set any attributes on a class, even if they aren't defined like `$oStrategie->newAttr = 6`, having a `__set` would allow your class to change the default behavior of creating a new property